# Rounding error when grouping by multiple categories

Tags: r, dplyr, rounding

Why are the values for `SE_daily` wrong? I expected it to round to the nearest integer (though I wanted a decimal), instead the decimal answer is completely wrong. What did I miss?

```
csv<-csv%>%group_by(id_num)%>%group_by(Month)%>%group_by(Day)%>%mutate(SE_daily=mean(SelfEsteem, na.rm=T))
head(csv[,c(1:5,28,181)])
> head(csv[,c(1:5,28,181)])
Source: local data frame [6 x 7]
Groups: Day [3]

    X.1     X id_num Month   Day SelfEsteem SE_daily
  <int> <int>  <int> <int> <int>      <int>    <dbl>
1     1     1     29     2    19          4 3.457944 #mean(4,4,3)= 4, expected answer= 3.66666666667
2     2     2     29     2    19          4 3.457944
3     3     3     29     2    19          3 3.457944
4     4     4     29     2    20          4 3.424242 #expected answer= 4
5     5     5     29     2    21          4 3.318182 #expected answer=4
6     6     6     29     2    21          4 3.318182
```

head of csv output:

```
structure(list(X.1 = 1:6, X = 1:6,
  id_num = c(29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L),
  Month = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
  Day = c(19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 21L),
  SelfEsteem = c(4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L),
  SE_daily = c(3.45794392523365, 3.45794392523365, 3.45794392523365,  3.42424242424242, 3.31818181818182, 3.31818181818182)), 
  .Names = c("X.1", "X", "id_num", "Month", "Day", "SelfEsteem", "SE_daily"),
  row.names = c(NA, -6L),
  class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you repost the `dput` structure there is an error in its current form `Error in structure(list(X.1 = 1:6, X = 1:6, id_num = c(29L, 29L, 29L,  : 
  object 'Day' not found`

Comment: Thanks for that. Not sure why the output was wrong....I did `dput(head(csv))` originally. I had to convert it to a data.frame then dput it again

Comment: I get the expected answer (the unrounded mean of each `Day`) when I run your code on the data sample you provided. Also the end result of `group_by(id_num)%>%group_by(Month)%>%group_by(Day)` is to group only by `Day`, since each `group_by` overrides the previous one. If you want to group by all three columns, do `group_by(id_num, Month, Day)`.

Comment: And they say piping is supposed to make code more readable!

Comment: @geryan ... to make code more readable -- but only if some spaces thrown in from time to time. Without the spaces I now do understand what "spaghetti" code truly means!

Comment: @UweBlock exactly my point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the expected output for SE_daily. It's possible that by piping the `group_by` commands instead of putting them in a single command you are looking at multiple `id_num` and `Months` that share a common `Day` (assuming that the provided data structure is only a subset of the entire data set)

```
library(dplyr)
csv %>%
  group_by(id_num, Month, Day) %>%
  mutate(SE_daily=mean(SelfEsteem, na.rm=TRUE))
```

output

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 7]
Groups: id_num, Month, Day [3]

    X.1     X id_num Month   Day SelfEsteem SE_daily
  <int> <int>  <int> <int> <int>      <int>    <dbl>
1     1     1     29     2    19          4 3.666667
2     2     2     29     2    19          4 3.666667
3     3     3     29     2    19          3 3.666667
4     4     4     29     2    20          4 4.000000
5     5     5     29     2    21          4 4.000000
6     6     6     29     2    21          4 4.000000
```